# How to change the position of buttons in jquery dialog box using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to display a form in jquery dialog box, like

```
$("#dialog-editinvitem").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 420,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            OK: function () {
               //...
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
        }
    });
```

it works fine. the buttons in the dialog-box are displayed at lower bottom of the dialog. but **i need to display the buttons at the top left corner of the dialog box after the dialog title bar.** I have tried with some jquery code to position the button panel like,

```
var btnset = $(this).parent().children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').html();
            $(this).parent().children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').remove();
            $("<div class='ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix'>" + btnset + "</div>").insertAfter($(this).parent().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar'));
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').css('float', 'left');
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').css('border-width', '0px 0px 1px 0px');
```

the button panel successfully positioned at top left corner but it doesnot fire button click events. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code, you are removing the dom element and it's associated event. try to clone the dom element and do some styling. once it finishes later u remove the original .
change this to

> $(this).parent().children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').remove();

this

```
var objbuttonPane = $(this).parent().children('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').clone(true);
//once you done with styling and positiong the button. you do  remove the original element  and append the cloned element
```

or why u need Jquery buttons ? you can put submit / links on whereever you choose and style them. just dont pass the button object in jquery dialog.  something like this .

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 420,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,       
        close: function () {
        }
    });
```

demo: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79rDD/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to prepend the button element position while opening dialog , just like the code snippet below

```
$('#dialog-editinvitem').dialog({
  open: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).before($(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane'));
  },
  ...
```